# Homotopics curves

Tags: general-topology

We are in the plane (x,y).
We have two periodic (closed) planar curves : (x1(t),y1(t)) which is a simple loop and (x2(t),y2(t)) which is a limaçon.

Are these two curves are homotopic ?

Comment: Depends upon the Limacon. If it is not looped, then they are homotopic. If it is, then it is a wedge of circles, which is not homotopically equivalent to the circle( can be seen from their respective Fundamental Groups).

Comment: @elena did you get my solution??

Answer (score 1):

Of course they are homotopic since $\mathbb R^2$ is contractible, so any subspace of $\mathbb R^2$ is homotopic to a single point, lets say the origin.Just recall the definition of homotopy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy#Formal_definition. Here the map will be $H:\mathbb R\times I→\mathbb R^2$, s.t $H(t,0)=(x_1(t),y_1(t))$ and $H(t,1)=(x_2(t),y_2(t))$.

Comment: You mean to say a circle is homotopic to a point?

Comment: Not in general, but inside $\mathbb R^2$, yes. Just recall the definition of homotopy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy#Formal_definition. Here the map will be $H:\mathbb R\times I\to \mathbb R^2$, s.t $H(t,0)=(x_1(t),y_1(t))$ and $H(x,1)=(x_2(t),y_2(t)).$

Comment: @SoumyaSinha "a circle is homotopic to a point" - mathematically makes no sense. There is something called homotopically equivalent.

Comment: Yes inside $\mathbb{R}^2$ they are homotopic. It is unclear as to what the OP wants us to answer.